# Is it possible to have mybinder download a 'custom.js' from github, and use this Keyboard Shortcut Customization file to launch the docker?

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

[mybinder](http://mybinder.org) could launch a customized docker based on `requirements.txt`, which contains the packages that needs to be installed, such as

```
matplotlib
numpy
```

is it possible to have mybinder download a 'custom.js' from github, and use this [Keyboard Shortcut Customization file](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/4.x/examples/Notebook/rstversions/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html) to launch the docker?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the use curl to get the `custom.js` from Github as a line before the `mkdir` command in the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58172073/8508004) to do this.