# Connecting to google colab via local system

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I've been tasked to solve a ML/DL problem.

But due to the processing limitations of my system the progress of developing the program further has come to a halt. It is a requirement of my program that it uses a GUI for the layman user, which I've already designed and implemented.

Now due to system limitations, I was wondering if I could somehow connect this python GUI instance on my local machine to Google Colab. The user could then use the GUI interface to upload files to google colab and upon pressing the submit button google colab would import these files. It would then do the ML/DL processing on these files and return some output back to the GUI interface for the user.

Any ideas of how I would achieve this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630751/simple-ui-on-top-of-colab) or [Anvil](https://anvil.works/learn/tutorials/google-colab-to-web-app) solve your task? They create a webapp of the notebooks.