# Google Colab. How to hide the python code for readers

Tags: google-colaboratory

I would like to hide the code of a cell for the readers.
I know that you can use #@title  to hide code in a cell.
However, if the reader doble click on the title or right mouse and select show code, he/she will be able to see the code again.

What I need is that nobody will be able to see the code behind. I want that they only were able to run the code and interact with it using the widgets.

Is there any way to do that?
Thank you very much.
Appreciated any insight on this question.

Comment: I guess you want to create some sort of [Simple UI on top of Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630751/simple-ui-on-top-of-colab)

Comment: I will definitevly check that. It sounds llike what I need. Thank you very much.